# Is aggregate query better in production environment?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I am using both find and aggregate query in my application based on use case. Just wanted to know what are the drawbacks of aggregate operation if it is deployed in production having a sharded environment?

```
{testarray:[{"val1":"xxxx","val2":50%},{"val1":"yyy","val2":80%}]
```

containing around 5000 document inside sub array

Comment: The drawback is that the mongos does some of the aggregation too and so can consume more CPU and memory than the documentation hints at initially, other than that I have no idea what your asking

Comment: @Sammaye wanted to know is aggregate a better option than find or we should go with find as much as possible

Comment: Typically I would go with find as much as possible, aggregate is something quite different and requires a lot of work for $group etc

Comment: @Sammaye is it going to impact performance wise as well?

Comment: Oh yes, if you are doing a lot of aggregates it will be the same as doing it in SQL, the same that is

Comment: @Sammaye Is their a work around where we can pull out any specific object from sub array without using unwind, in a collection?

Comment: Not really, $unwind is designed for that atm, you can only project one element of a subdocument out using elemMatch atm

Comment: @Sammaye just trying to understand, how feasible it would be to do unwind when my subarray is very large in the production environment, and would it lead to performance issue?

Comment: Can you show an example of your query? And how big are we talking about?

Comment: @Sammaye it looks something like this:

Comment: Try adding it to the question

Comment: @Sammaye just added it to the question

Comment: Yes that would be a performance hit, it has to unwind all 5,000 of those god knows how many simultaneous times you do that query